# error while copying a file from one folder to another in vba. file format gets changed while copying line by line..it gets changed to alphanumric kind

Tags: vba

This is the code for copying line by line:

```
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myLine As String
Dim FileNum As Long
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
headersepfile = HeaderSepFilePath
myFileName = workPath
FileNum = FreeFile
Open myFileName For Input As FileNum   
Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, myLine
    Debug.Print myLine
    Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(headersepfile, True, False)
     outFile.WriteLine myLine
Loop
```

Comment: Instead of recreating the output file handle during every iteration of your loop, do it once. Move the `Set outFile` line above your loop.

Comment: Also, please specify what "chaged to alphanumeric kind" is supposed to mean. If you just want to copy a file, there is no reason to do it line by line anyway, that's terribly inefficient and won't work with binary files. Use `objFSO.CopyFile` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: I'd guess OP means that while the file is being updated, he can see a temp filename in Windows Explorer.  Either way objFSO.CopyFile would be far more efficient...